# OkHttp Upload an image app:DexBug

Tags: okhttp

I'm a beginner on Andriod. I am using OkHttp to Upload an image by post method. 
So i added okio-1.6.0 jar file to my libs folder and following are my code i keep getting app:DexBug when I run my app. I tried right click the jar and add it to library and made sure  compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar') is in my gradle

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    MultipartBuilder builder = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);
    builder.addFormDataPart("upload", null, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150223-130123.jpg")));
    RequestBody requestBody = builder.build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(Url3)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();




    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            System.out.println("request = " + request.urlString());
            System.out.println("e.getLocalizedMessage() = " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("response = " + response.body().string());
        }
    });


Gradle File

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.binyiliu.funfacts"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    //mutiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
   compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.4.0'
   compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')
}
```

I've been stuck on this for days.
Thanks in advance.

Here are the log

:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokio/Sink;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1.372 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: please provide a log file

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a dependency library twice: using a *.jar* but also using a *Gradle dependency* for **Okio**.

Delete either

> compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')

(and also the .jar from the disk - you don't need it),

or, delete the Gradle dependency:

> compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'